# Does anyone know what <<= does in a javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 10;
var b = 3;
a <<= b;
document.write(a);
```

I know the answer is 80 but how does the code achieve this?

many thanks

Comment: *"the answer is 160"*. Really ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've changed the code now and the answer comes out as 80

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same construct than `+=`, but it's based on the `<<` operator ([left bitwise shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators)) instead of the `+` operator.

```
a <<= b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a << b;
```

This compound operator is called a [left shift assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Left_shift_assignment).

To make your use-case clearer :

```
a <<= 1 ; // multiplies a small integer by 2
a <<= 2 ; // multiplies a small integer by 4
a <<= 3 ; // multiplies a small integer by 8
...
```

Comment: Ah didn't know what the `=` meant. Learned something new :)